# Why does Int32.MinValue - 1 return Int32.MaxValue?

Tags: c#, clr

When I execute the following code, I have (for me) some unexpected behaviour.

```
int i = Int32.MinValue;
i--;
if (i == Int32.MaxValue)
{
    Console.WriteLine("i == Int32.MaxValue");
}
i++;
if (i == Int32.MinValue)
{
    Console.WriteLine("i == Int32.MinValue");
}
```

Why doesn't the -1 on Int32.MinValue throw an Exception?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because of the underflow the values wrap around.

You need to use a [`checked`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74b4xzyw.aspx) section if you want overflows/underflows to throw.

> The checked keyword is used to explicitly enable overflow checking for integral-type arithmetic operations and conversions.

Answer (score 5):

From MSDN:

> When integer overflow occurs, what happens depends on the execution context, which can be checked or unchecked. In a checked context, an OverflowException is thrown. In an unchecked context, the most significant bits of the result are discarded and execution continues. Thus, C# gives you the choice of handling or ignoring overflow.

[Link to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.overflowexception%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

C#, like C, doesn't actually do overflow/underflow checks unless explicitly written/told to do so. As such, it has no problem subtracting 1 from `100...000` and getting `011...111`.

Answer (score 2):

`int` is a [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) binary number.